# Randomizer Conditional Probability Problem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

- The Randomizer holds the 6-sided die in one fist and the 8-sided die in the other.
- The Roller selects one of the Randomizer’s fists and covertly takes the die.
- The Roller rolls the die in secret and reports the result to the table.

a) If the number rolled is 1-6 then P(six-sided) = ?

My method: $P(6-sided|1-6 rolled)=\frac{|6-sided\cap1-6rolled|}{|1-6 rolled|}=\frac{1}{2}$. The answer is $\frac{4}{7}$. What did I do wrong?

Comment: How did you get $1/2$?

Comment: I made a tree with 2 nodes representing the different dice and then 14 further nodes representing the numbers you could land. For the denominator there's 12 outcomes since there's 1-6 on the first die and 1-6 on the second die. For the numerator there's 6 outcomes since out of all "1-6 rolled" outcomes 6 of them belong to the six sided die. 6/12=1/2

Comment: You are missing a couple of outcomes on the second die. You need to include them so that you can properly calculate the probability of rolling a number between $1$ and $6$ inclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method assumes the 14 outcomes are equally likely, but they are not. It is harder to roll a 1 with the 8-sided die than with the 6-sided die.

The correct approach is to use Bayes's rule.
$$P(\text{6-sided} \mid \text{rolled 1-6})
= \frac{P(\text{6-sided, rolled 1-6})}{P(\text{rolled 1-6})}
= \frac{P(\text{6-sided, rolled 1-6})}{P(\text{6-sided, rolled 1-6}) + P(\text{8-sided, rolled 1-6})}
= \frac{\frac{1}{2} \cdot 1}{\frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{6}{8}}
= \frac{4}{7}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $D_6$ be the event that the six-sided die is selected and $D_8$ be the event that the eight-sided die is selected. Also let $R_6$ be the event that a number between $1$ and $6$ is reported by the roller.

You then wrote

$$
P(D_6 \mid R_6) = \frac{P(D_6 \cap R_6)}{P(R_6)}
$$

This is correct. But the value of this is not $1/2$. You may have deduced that $P(D_6 \cap R_6) = P(D_6) = 1/2$. But what is $P(R_6)$, the *a priori* probability that a number between $1$ and $6$ is reported? It is not $1$.

Can you take it from there?